# I have installed Ubuntu 17.04, I am not able to connect to internet

Tags: networking

I cannot do anything with internet and have tried editing file `network manager.conf` and changing value to True and restarted the machine still not working.

And the mouse does not work automatically, I have to probe it every time I login, any permanent solutions to that?

Comment: Hi, could you provide some system information? Computer manufacturer,  RAM size etc

Comment: Anybody able and willing to help you will need more information regarding your hardware and what you tried. This https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide might help you improve your question with regard to wifi.

Comment: It's desktop assembled Amd processor 64 bit 4gb ram

Comment: tried manual setting up IPv4 helped

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/465171/openvpn-setup-with-pia-connects-but-no-internet?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running the command contained in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/905045, I had the same problem and I solved only with that post. After the "touch" command you have to restart the network-manager demon.

Comment: Your link is to a duplicate. You should change your link to the original which is much nicer anyway. Plus you should include the `touch...` command in thus answer. It makes life easier for everyone and gets you more up votes. +1 from me though to counter the negative 1 this answer had.