# tun0 doesn't have internet access

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, openvpn, curl

I'm using OpenVPN on tun0 (Ubuntu 16/EC2), I can successfully start it with `systemctl start openvpn@Ireland` (PIA's Irish cluster), but the interface doesn't have Internet access:

```
curl --interface tun0 -vv http://icanhazip.com/plain
*   Trying 104.20.17.242...
* Local Interface tun0 is ip 10.34.10.6 using address family 2
* Local port: 0
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:10f2...
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:11f2...
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:10f2...
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6814:11f2...
```

This is my /etc/openvpn/Ireland.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ireland.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher aes-128-cbc
auth sha1
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.rsa.2048.pem
ca ca.rsa.2048.crt
disable-occ
auth-user-pass secrets
route-nopull
```

Notice the last line: `route-nopull`. Without that, my SSH connection immediately drops, plus I don't want the VPN connection to be the default, I only want to selectively use it with cURL.

This is my routing table (this is a very gray area for me):

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.32.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.34.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
172.31.32.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**How do I give my tun0 internet access?**

Thanks a lot.

PS
I would also like to *understand* the solution.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem with `pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway`

Comment: @JackCole I haven't mate.

Comment: My googling found that what we're looking for is "split tunneling". The common tactic seems to be using iptables to forward traffic to a specific interface based on the user. I followed a couple guides but couldn't get it working yet.

Comment: @JackCole I had this question answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/992624/vpn-client-doesnt-have-internet-connection